# Adding xCode '.a' Library file to repository SVN ignored

Tags: svn, xcode

I am not able to upload the file "libYAJLIPhone.a" to a SVN repository.

I'm trying to set up an SVN repository for an iPhone application. I've set up various "global-ignores" and auto-props to exclude the build directory.

But with and without these ignore parameters and/or auto-props I'm still not able add the file "libYAJLIPhone.a"?

I'm using Cornerstone as a frontend. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your exact 'global ignores' string?

Comment: Also, is the file you're trying to add in a folder that is under souce control? If the directory the file is in isn't under control, you won't be the option to add it (in TortseSVN). What client are you using?

Comment: Hi, 

the folder is under source control (all the other files are added)

I'm using cornerstone as the client

I've tried with 'global ignores' commented out and :
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store *~.nib *.pbxuser .xvpics build *.mode1 *.mode1v3

and :

global-ignores = build *~.nib *.so *.pbxuser *.mode* *.perspective*

thanks

Comment: I have managed to import the file through terminal. I guess the problem must lie within the Cornerstone app. Shame

Answer (score 13):

Actually SVN is ignoring .a files when you import a project. You have to manually add the .a files

For example :

svn add libOCMock.a

Then you can commit the library to your repo.

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Answer (score 9):

A quick way to add them from the command line (including subfolders):

```
$ find . -name *.a -exec svn add {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

Might help someone...

Modifying ~/.subversion/config has no effect on cornerstone. In order make Cornerstone accept .a files.

1. Go to Cornerstone preferences.
2. Choose 'Subversion' tab
3. Choose 'General'
4. Uncheck 'Use default global ignores', that will enable the text box for editing.
5. Remove *.a from the box.

Above is for Cornerstone 2.0.2 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps to add a  .a file into svn

**1.** Go to Terminal

**2**  Type  .cd ~/.subversion/

**3.** open -a TextEdit config

**4.** Goto section "# global-ignores" in the config file and remove "*.a"

**5.** Unlock and save the file

**6.** Navigate to the folder where the .a files are present in your PROJECT PATH

**7.** Type "svn add FILENAME.a"

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something strange going on with the global ignore list in Cornerstone. If you copy something like this in there (from ~/.subversion/config), then .a files will appear (*.a is in the global ignore list by default, but not in this list):

> *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store

(they may need to be comma delimited to appear correctly in Cornerstone; they're whitespace delimited in the svn config file, but it seems to actually work either way, regardless of how the dialog presents them). Then I found, if I selected to use the defaults in the Cornerstone subversion config dialog, I got another slightly different global ignore list which also didn't include *.a, and that worked, so I stuck with it.